# How to use cordova plugin in react.js page

Tags: reactjs, cordova

Excuse me，Is this problem solved? I also have the same troubles.I use cordova-plugin-network-information

```
let networkState = window.navigator.connect.type; 
alert(networkState);
```

The result is unknown.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate more on the problem specifics? Also, please provide [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How to use cordova plugin in react.js page??

Answer (score 0):

In browser the network state is always Unknown.